# Magento 2 - How I can get the filesize of a pdf file

Tags: magento2, php, magento2.3, error

I try to get the php `filesize` of a pdf file but I have the following error:

```
Exception #0 (Exception): Warning: filesize(): stat failed
```

This is my code:

```
<?php
$_helper = $this->helper('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Output');
$_product = $block->getProduct();
$usermanual  = $this->helper('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Output')->productAttribute($block, $block->getProduct()->getUserManual(), 'user_manual'); 
?>
<div class="products-attachments">
    <h2><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('User Manuals and Fitting Guides Downloads: ') ?></h2>

        <?php $attr = explode(";",$this->helper('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Output')->productAttribute($block, $block->getProduct()->getUserManual(), 'user_manual')); 
            if(isset($usermanual)) {
        ?>
            <ul class="custom-attribute">
                <?php foreach ($attr as $attrValue) { 
                    $pdf = '.pdf';
                    $file = $attrValue;
                    $url = $block->getUrl('pub/media/attachments/');
                    $filesize = filesize($url.$file.$pdf); // bytes
                    $filesize = round($filesize / 1024 / 1024, 1); // megabytes with 1 digit

                    echo "The size of your file is $filesize MB.";

                ?>
                    <li><a href="<?php echo $block->getUrl("pub/media/attachments/")?><?php echo $attrValue; ?><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('.pdf') ?>"><img src="<?php echo $block->getUrl("pub/media/attachments/")?>pdf.gif"/> <?php echo $attrValue; ?><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('.pdf') ?></a><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Size:') ?> </li>
         <?php
                } 
        ?>
            </ul>
         <?php
            }
        ?>
</div>
```

What I do wrong?
Or how I can do this in Magento 2? I found something in the `vendor/magento/framework/File/Size.php` but how I can use the function in my code?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this way...

**First in your block file**

```
private $dataHelper;
public function __construct(
   .....
    \Vendor\Module\Helper\Data $dataHelper,
   ....
) {
    .....
    $this->dataHelper = $dataHelper;
    .....
}

public function getFileSize($attachment)
    {
        $attachmentPath = \Vendor\Module\Helper\Data::MEDIA_PATH.$attachment;
        $fileSize = $this->dataHelper->getFileSize($attachmentPath);
        return $fileSize;
    }
```

**Then your Helper file add below function**

```
    private $filesystem;
    private $mediaDirectory;
    public function __construct(
       .....
       \Magento\Framework\Filesystem $filesystem,
       ....
    ) {
        .....
        $this->mediaDirectory = $filesystem->getDirectoryWrite(DirectoryList::MEDIA);
        .....
    }

 public function getFileSize($file)
    {
        $fileSize = $this->mediaDirectory->stat($file)['size'];
        $readableSize = $this->convertToReadableSize($fileSize);
        return $readableSize;
    }

    /**
     * Convert size into readable format
     */
    public function convertToReadableSize($size)
    {
        $base = log($size) / log(1024);
        $suffix = ["", " KB", " MB", " GB", " TB"];
        $f_base = floor($base);
        return round(pow(1024, $base - floor($base)), 1) . $suffix[$f_base];
    }
```

**then in phtml file you get file size below way**

```
<?php $block->getFileSize($attachment->getFile()) ?>
```

Comment: I don't think we need \Vendor\Module\Helper\Data::MEDIA_PATH, the correct path don't need 'pub/media', it should be something look like this: $this->mediaDirectory->stat('video-widget/video-thumbnail-1/98I_ST9GZSE_thumbnail.jpg'), tried and work.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to run `filesize()` on a remote asset, which may not worked based off of the settings in your `php.ini`.

The way you might want to do it is like so:

**First, extend the block**

Create your own block class for this template extending the original: (I make an assumption about the class used here, confirm your own)

```php
class MyBlock extends \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\AbstractProduct
{
    public function __construct(\Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\Context $context, array $data = []) {
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }
}
```

**Second, use the `\Magento\Framework\Filesystem` class**

You can inject it in to your constructor and use the `getDirectoryRead(\Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList::MEDIA)` function to get a reference to the `pub/media` directory:

```php
class MyBlock extends \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\AbstractProduct
{
    protected $_mediaDirectory;

    public function __construct(\Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\Context $context, \Magento\Framework\Filesystem $fs, array $data = []) {
        $this->_mediaDirectory = $fs->getDirectoryRead(\Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList::MEDIA);
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }
}
```

**Third, stat the URI**

You can use the `ReadInterface::stat($path)` method to get the output:

```php
public function getPdfSize($pdfName) {
    $fullPdfName = sprintf('attachments/%s.pdf', $pdfName);

    $statResults = $this->_mediaDirectory->stat($fullPdfName);
    return is_array($statResults) ? $statResults['size'] : -1; //default to -1 here if we fail to stat
}
```

Then you can just call the `getPdfSize($file)` function where you previously call `filesize()`.

You can do this in other ways, such as using a viewmodel or helper, but hopefully this gives you a good enough of an idea of how the functionality works